# Spring JSON View: ApplicationObjectSupport does not run in an ApplicationContext

Tags: java, json, spring

I'm trying to use a Json View for Spring (http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/) (org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView) but whenever I write a controller class that extends `AbstractController` I get the following Error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationObjectSupport instance [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.json.JsonView] does not run in an ApplicationContext

The weird thing is, that when I implement the Controller interface directly and do not inherit, *it is fine*. The error only happens when I inherit from `AbstractController`.

In my current case though I would like to extend `AbstractFormController` and hence can't write a class that does not inherit from `AbstractController`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Note: this isn't part of core Spring, this is from http://spring-json.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Good point, edited the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a rather misleading error message, it's actually complaining that the JsonView is not running inside an app context. What it means is that the `JsonView` bean was not instantiated by Spring, but that you instantiated it yourself (`JsonView` extends `ApplicationObjectSupport`, and should therefore be Spring-managed).

However, you haven't given us any of your code, so it's hard to tell for sure. I'm guessing your controller is instantiating `JsonView` itself? You need to let Spring do that, either by injecting a `JsonView` bean into the controller, or perhaps using a `ViewResolver` (if Spring-Json supplies one).

Comment: couldn't be explained better :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing Java configuration ( as opposed to XML ), in your configuration class you may want to call `setApplicationContext` method on object that is complaining.

This is what did the trick for me in Spring MVC 3.2.2 when trying to initialize `ContentNegotiatingViewResolver` in Java.

Here is the sample configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
...
public class MyConfig
{
  @Inject
  private ApplicationContext appContext;

  @Bean
  public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver contentNegotiatingViewResolver ( )
  {
     ContentNegotiatingViewResolver retVal = 
       new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver( );

     ...

     retVal.setApplicationContext( appContext );

     return retVal;
  }
}
```